# Django, delete all cookie

Tags: django, cookies, django-sessions

I want to delete all cookies for the user under my domain name. I know `logout()` method removes the session, but it seems like some of my apps are generating a few more cookies that needs to be cleansed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry but this was just perfect: http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2359/2534644455_4cb78c0d2c.jpg

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django logout(redirect to home page) .. Delete cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275357/django-logoutredirect-to-home-page-delete-cookie)

Comment: Not a duplicate, since that question asks about a single cookie, not all cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275357/django-logoutredirect-to-home-page-delete-cookie). I think there's an answer for you there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but:

```py
def some_view(request):
    response = HttpResponseRedirect('/any-page-you-want/')
    for cookie in request.COOKIES:
        response.delete_cookie(cookie)
    return response
```