# How to delete cookies in Django?

Tags: python, django, authentication, cookies, django-cookies

I'm trying to develop login page for a web site. I stored users which logged on correctly to a cookie with `set_cookie`. But I don't know how to delete the cookie. So, how can I delete the cookie to make a user log out?

Comment: check this question, it should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275357/django-logoutredirect-to-home-page-delete-cookie here's documentation for django 1.4: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.delete_cookie

Comment: Why aren't you using Django's auth framework? And even if you can't use that for some reason, why aren't you using the sessions framework rather than raw cookies?

Comment: I am move the code from tornado to django. And the souce was developed using cookie. I dont want change a lot to the code.

Comment: Yes, I have read the doc, and questions at [django-logoutredirect-to-home-page-delete-cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275357/django-logoutredirect-to-home-page-delete-cookie)

Answer (score 53):

Setting cookies :

```
    def login(request):
        response = HttpResponseRedirect('/url/to_your_home_page')
        response.set_cookie('cookie_name1', 'cookie_name1_value')
        response.set_cookie('cookie_name2', 'cookie_name2_value')
        return response
```

Deleting cookies :

```
    def logout(request):
        response = HttpResponseRedirect('/url/to_your_login')
        response.delete_cookie('cookie_name1')
        response.delete_cookie('cookie_name2')
        return response
```

Comment: deleting cookie this way still remains in browser, first hand experience :/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply delete whatever you've stored in the cookie - this way, even though the cookie is there, it no longer contain any information required for session tracking and the user needs to authorize again.

(Also, this seems like a duplicate of [Django logout(redirect to home page) .. Delete cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275357/django-logoutredirect-to-home-page-delete-cookie))

Answer (score 0):

For example, you set cookies as shown below. *You must return the object otherwise cookies are not set to a browser and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622793/how-to-set-and-get-cookies-in-django/76599637#76599637) explaining how to set and get cookies in Django:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    response = render(request, 'index.html', {})
    response.set_cookie('name', 'John') # Here
    response.cookies['age'] = 27 # Here
    return response # Must return the object
```

Then, you can delete the cookies with [response.delete_cookie()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.delete_cookie) as shown below. *You must return the object otherwise cookies are not deleted from a browser:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    response = render(request, 'index.html', {})
    response.delete_cookie('name')
    response.delete_cookie('age')
    return response # Must return the object
```