# In django python, delete a cookie which is basically a session ID

Tags: django, session-cookies

In django I want to delete a cookie  or set it to null what is the method to do that in views.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401398/how-to-clear-cookies-using-django

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
  response.delete_cookie('cookie_name', domain="cookie_domain")
  return response
```

More details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.delete_cookie